# Good getaway place from NYC for some peace and quiet?

Tags: new-york-city

Been in NYC most of my life, have worked in the city for over a decade now. Lately I've been getting burnt out, and ideally, I'd like to get away for a week, hopefully somewhere not too far, that's away from the hustle and bustle of the city.

I'm thinking of something close to the beach (or on the beach), a small apartment or house where I could just write and think, with a kitchen where I could cook a bit, exercise, relax and just enjoy the sun. Internet is a must though (I know that sounds a bit hypocritical); I wouldn't be using it much, but it'd be important enough to have around, especially for contact with family/friends and work.

I'm sure many such places exist in LI and Jersey: ideally I'd look for something slightly farther away (more a psychological thing than anything else, to reinforce I'm "away"), but if something close is most feasible then I'd go for it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Your question covers basically the entire Long Island and Jersey Shore not to mention places in Delaware and Connecticut.  Beyond that your question is very opinion based so it's likely to be put on hold, so if you would like to focus it a little more.

Comment: Places to begin with would be Rockaway beach, I would start there to see how you like it, the beach is really long and quiet most of the time, see how you like it